# Verify line endings from a text created by perl script

Tags: vim, perl, text, newlines

I am interested in seeing the contents of a text file in hex mode.

I have tried `:%!xxd` and the problem is that I can not really understand which
hex code represents each letter e.g. when you use an editor like Ultra Edit as you go over the hex code the corresponding letter is highlighted.

So how can I do something similar in my case?

To give you a context of my problem, I have a `perl` script that creates the file and I want to make sure that each line ends only with a `0x0A` (LF).

Strange enough opening the file in `vim` and using `:set list`, I can see only `$` even if I explicitly did on the script `$line .= "\r\n"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
open my $fh, '>', 'test.txt'
    or die "$!";
binmode $fh;
print $fh "QWERTY\n";
```

You only see `$` in `vim` because by default, `listchars` for end of line only contains `$`. From `:help listchars`:

```
'listchars' 'lcs'       string  (default "eol:$")
                        global
                        {not in Vi}
        Strings to use in 'list' mode and for the :list command.  It is a
        comma separated list of string settings.
                                                        lcs-eol
          eol:c         Character to show at the end of each line.  When
                        omitted, there is no extra character at the end of the
                        line.
```

To know actual line ending, you can try `file` or `cat`:

```
$ file test.txt 
test.txt: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
$ cat -e test.txt 
QWERTY^M$
```

Comment: +1.This works. BTW does adding just a `\n` translate to a LF in all systems?

Comment: @Jim:setting binmode to filehandle force `\n` to `LF` in all system.

Comment: I don't have an explicit file handle. I contruct the string by doing `$data .= $line."\n"` and I pass them to another library

Comment: How do you pass to other library? write to it or require?

Comment: Can you give me the portion of your script which attched data to mail?

Comment: @Jim: Your mail is sent as **text/html** so the line break of html is different from plain text. If you sent as text, see here: http://www.justskins.com/forums/mime-lite-not-recognizing-75660.html

Answer (score 0):

A POSIX portable means of viewing non-printable characters in a text file might be:

```
sed -n l <file
```

Besides being portable, `sed` will also default to printing the line twice if you eschew the `-n` - once with nonprintable characters represented with C-style or octal escapes immediately followed by another printing of the line as it would normally display.

You might also do:

```
sed =\;l <file
```

To separate the pairs of output lines by line number.